# Program is looping too many times, and producing weird behaviour

Tags: c, loops

I am attempting to write a program that will turn hexadecimal input into base64 encoded output. More specifically, the input:

```
0x49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d
```

(which is "I'm killing your brain like a poisonous mushroom" in ASCII — this is important for later!)

The code below is what I have come up with; it may be over-complicated but in my head each step makes sense. Now, it works with a simple input such as 0x4d616e but not for the longer string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char b64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

void base64encode(char * data) {

    size_t data_size = strlen(data);
    size_t last_block_size = data_size%3;
    size_t padding_chars = last_block_size==0?0:3-last_block_size;
    size_t num_blocks = last_block_size==0?data_size/3:(data_size/3)+1;

    int i1,i2,i3,i4 = 0;

    uint32_t * blocks = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*num_blocks);

    memset(blocks,0,sizeof(uint32_t)*num_blocks);

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(data); i++)
        blocks[i/3] |= data[i] << (2-(i%3))*8;

    for (int i=0; i<num_blocks; i++){
        i1 = (blocks[i] & 0xfc0000) >> 18;
        i2 = (blocks[i] & 0x03f000) >> 12;
        i3 = ((i==num_blocks-1) && (padding_chars==2))?64:(blocks[i] & 0x000fc0) >> 6;
        i4 = ((i==num_blocks-1) && (padding_chars>=1))?64:(blocks[i] & 0x00003f);

        printf("%c%c%c%c",b64[i1],b64[i2],b64[i3],b64[i4]);

    }

    free(blocks);
}

int hex_char_to_raw (char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '0': return 0x0;
        case '1': return 0x1;
        case '2': return 0x2;
        case '3': return 0x3;
        case '4': return 0x4;
        case '5': return 0x5;
        case '6': return 0x6;
        case '7': return 0x7;
        case '8': return 0x8;
        case '9': return 0x9;
        case 'A': return 0xA;
        case 'B': return 0xB;
        case 'C': return 0xC;
        case 'D': return 0xD;
        case 'E': return 0xE;
        case 'F': return 0xF;
        default: return -1;
    }
}

void hex_to_raw(char * data) {

    for (int i=2; i < strlen(data); i++){
        if ( (data[i]<48) || ((data[i]>57)&&(data[i]<65)) || ((data[i]>70)&&(data[i]<97)) || (data[i]>102) ) {
            printf("ERROR: Invalid Hex Character '%c' in input at character %d\n",data[i],i-1);
            return;
        } else if ( (data[i] <= 102) && (data[i] >= 97) )
            data[i] = data[i]-32; // Transform all lower case letters to corresponding upper case letters
    }

    char * buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(data)-2));

    for (int i=2; i <= strlen(data); i++) {
        if (i != strlen(data))
            buffer[i-2] = data[i];
        else
            buffer[i-2] = '\0';
    }

    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    char * binary = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)/2));

    printf("%zu %zu %zu %zu\n",sizeof(char)*(strlen(data)-2),sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)/2),strlen(buffer), strlen(data));

    for (int i=0; i < strlen(buffer); i=i+2) {
        printf("\ti=%u i/2=%u buffer[i]=%c buffer[i+1]=%c\n",i,i/2,buffer[i],buffer[i+1]);
        binary[i/2] = (hex_char_to_raw(buffer[i]) << 4) | (hex_char_to_raw(buffer[i+1]));
    }

    free(buffer);
    printf("%s\n", binary);

    base64encode(binary);

    free(binary);
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s [input]\n",argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }


    hex_to_raw(argv[1]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following:

```
andrew@Andrews-MacBook-Air  Sat Jun 04 02:11:55  ~/Documents/Cryptopals Challenges/Set 1/Challenge 1 
     ->  ./test 0x49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d
49276D206B696C6C696E6720796F757220627261696E206C696B65206120706F69736F6E6F7573206D757368726F6F6D
96 48 96 98
    i=0 i/2=0 buffer[i]=4 buffer[i+1]=9
    i=2 i/2=1 buffer[i]=2 buffer[i+1]=7
    i=4 i/2=2 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=D
    i=6 i/2=3 buffer[i]=2 buffer[i+1]=0
    i=8 i/2=4 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=B
    i=10 i/2=5 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=9
    i=12 i/2=6 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=C
    i=14 i/2=7 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=C
    i=16 i/2=8 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=9
    i=18 i/2=9 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=E
    i=20 i/2=10 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=7
    i=22 i/2=11 buffer[i]=2 buffer[i+1]=0
    i=24 i/2=12 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=9
    i=26 i/2=13 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=F
    i=28 i/2=14 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=5
    i=30 i/2=15 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=2
    i=32 i/2=16 buffer[i]=2 buffer[i+1]=0
    i=34 i/2=17 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=2
    i=36 i/2=18 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=2
    i=38 i/2=19 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=1
    i=40 i/2=20 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=9
    i=42 i/2=21 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=E
    i=44 i/2=22 buffer[i]=2 buffer[i+1]=0
    i=46 i/2=23 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=C
    i=48 i/2=24 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=9
    i=50 i/2=25 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=B
    i=52 i/2=26 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=5
    i=54 i/2=27 buffer[i]=2 buffer[i+1]=0
    i=56 i/2=28 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=1
    i=58 i/2=29 buffer[i]=2 buffer[i+1]=0
    i=60 i/2=30 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=0
    i=62 i/2=31 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=F
    i=64 i/2=32 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=9
    i=66 i/2=33 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=3
    i=68 i/2=34 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=F
    i=70 i/2=35 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=E
    i=72 i/2=36 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=F
    i=74 i/2=37 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=5
    i=76 i/2=38 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=3
    i=78 i/2=39 buffer[i]=2 buffer[i+1]=0
    i=80 i/2=40 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=D
    i=82 i/2=41 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=5
    i=84 i/2=42 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=3
    i=86 i/2=43 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=8
    i=88 i/2=44 buffer[i]=7 buffer[i+1]=2
    i=90 i/2=45 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=F
    i=92 i/2=46 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=F
    i=94 i/2=47 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=D
    i=96 i/2=48 buffer[i]=I buffer[i+1]='
    i=98 i/2=49 buffer[i]=m buffer[i+1]= 
    i=100 i/2=50 buffer[i]=k buffer[i+1]=i
    i=102 i/2=51 buffer[i]=l buffer[i+1]=l
    i=104 i/2=52 buffer[i]=i buffer[i+1]=n
    i=106 i/2=53 buffer[i]=g buffer[i+1]= 
    i=108 i/2=54 buffer[i]=y buffer[i+1]=o
    i=110 i/2=55 buffer[i]=u buffer[i+1]=r
    i=112 i/2=56 buffer[i]=  buffer[i+1]=b
    i=114 i/2=57 buffer[i]=r buffer[i+1]=a
    i=116 i/2=58 buffer[i]=i buffer[i+1]=n
    i=118 i/2=59 buffer[i]=  buffer[i+1]=l
    i=120 i/2=60 buffer[i]=i buffer[i+1]=k
    i=122 i/2=61 buffer[i]=e buffer[i+1]= 
    i=124 i/2=62 buffer[i]=a buffer[i+1]= 
    i=126 i/2=63 buffer[i]=p buffer[i+1]=o
    i=128 i/2=64 buffer[i]=i buffer[i+1]=s
    i=130 i/2=65 buffer[i]=o buffer[i+1]=n
    i=132 i/2=66 buffer[i]=o buffer[i+1]=u
    i=134 i/2=67 buffer[i]=s buffer[i+1]= 
    i=136 i/2=68 buffer[i]=m buffer[i+1]=u
    i=138 i/2=69 buffer[i]=s buffer[i+1]=h
    i=140 i/2=70 buffer[i]=r buffer[i+1]=o
    i=142 i/2=71 buffer[i]=o buffer[i+1]=m
    i=144 i/2=72 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=146 i/2=73 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=148 i/2=74 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=150 i/2=75 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=152 i/2=76 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=154 i/2=77 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=156 i/2=78 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=158 i/2=79 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=160 i/2=80 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=162 i/2=81 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=164 i/2=82 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=166 i/2=83 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=168 i/2=84 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=170 i/2=85 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=172 i/2=86 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=174 i/2=87 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=176 i/2=88 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=178 i/2=89 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=180 i/2=90 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=182 i/2=91 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=184 i/2=92 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=186 i/2=93 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=188 i/2=94 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=?
    i=190 i/2=95 buffer[i]=? buffer[i+1]=
I'm killing your brain like a poisonous mushroom????????????????????????????????????????????????
SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

It loops far too many times and garbled with the `buffer` data I seem to also get the ASCII version of the hex input. I can't see how this is happening, other than it must be happening with my calls to `hex_char_to_raw`. All of the `printf` statements are my attempts at debugging the code to see what is happening, I have printed the values that I am passing to `malloc` to see what is being allocated as well as intermediary values for some variables.

What is confusing me more is that it will work if I use a simpler hex string. Here is the output if I run it with 0x4d616e  ("Man")

```
andrew@Andrews-MacBook-Air  Sat Jun 04 02:11:56  ~/Documents/Cryptopals Challenges/Set 1/Challenge 1 
     ->  ./test 0x4d616e
4D616E
6 3 6 8
    i=0 i/2=0 buffer[i]=4 buffer[i+1]=D
    i=2 i/2=1 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=1
    i=4 i/2=2 buffer[i]=6 buffer[i+1]=E
Man
TWFu
```

If anybody could point me in the direction of finding what's going on I'd be most grateful. I am sure it is such a little thing, but I have been looking at this code for so long that I think a fresh pair of eyes may be useful.

Comment: `printf` is not really debugging. Time to learn using a Debugger.

Comment: `i4 = ((i==num_blocks-1) && (padding_chars>=1))?64:(blocks[i] & 0x00003f);` can lead to `i4==64` and `printf("%c",b64[64]);` prints a null character.  Is this intended>?

Comment: I have added the padding character '=' to the end of the b64 array, so it will print this character when required.

Comment: buffer = malloc(...) is not long enough. It needs to be strlen(data)-2+1. You are null-terminating buffer so you need an extra byte for that. Your method of allocating and copying the data minus the leading 0x is also very inefficient. You could simply do buffer = strdup(data+2);

Comment: Can you edit the code to only include the parts that're necessary to show the problem? `base64encode` seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: +1 to the comment about missing '\0'. This is a very common C programming error. In addition, you should consider doing away with all the buffering and write a very tight loop just processing 6 input hex digits at a time. Let stdio do the buffering for you, it's pretty good at it.

Comment: Don't ever write a loop like this:  `for(int i=0; i<strlen(data); i++)`  That is grotesquely inefficient.  You are calculating the string length *every single time* through the loop.  Instead, calculate the string length *once*, outside the loop, and then use that as a fixed loop bound.  That way the loop is O(n) rather than O(n**2).  This is a classic "no hire" check.

Comment: Just to make the code more readable you can use literal characters instead of the decimal representation: `if ( (data[i] <= 'f') && (data[i] >= 'a') )` and eliminate potential errors. Also using a local for `data[i]` will also make things more clear: `char c = data[i];`. Combining: from `if ( (data[i] <= 102) && (data[i] >= 97)` becomes `if ( (c <= 'f') && (c >= 'a') )`.

Answer (score -2):

Hans-Martin Mosner has indicate your fault，I added some details.
The first mistask:

```
char * buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(data)-2));

for (int i=2; i <= strlen(data); i++) {
    if (i != strlen(data))
        buffer[i-2] = data[i];
    else
        buffer[i-2] = '\0';
}
```

for example, "0x4d616e"
length is 8, not enough '\0'. So the buffer's size is 6. 
when you run at

```
buffer[i-2] = '\0';
```

i-2=6, it's over the buffer's size.

The second mistask:

```
for (int i=0; i < strlen(buffer); i=i+2) {
    printf("\ti=%u i/2=%u buffer[i]=%c buffer[i+1]=%c\n",i,i/2,buffer[i],buffer[i+1]);
    binary[i/2] = (hex_char_to_raw(buffer[i]) << 4) | (hex_char_to_raw(buffer[i+1]));
}
```

in this code, you don't add '\0' in buffer's end; so when you printf buffer, it show many unreadable code。
You should add `binary[i/2] = '\0';` after for(){...}. 
Of course, you should add 1 when you malloc binary.

Comment: You forgot to mention the loop-invariant calls to `strlen` from within the loop.  Instant "no hire" if we see something like this.  That just turns an O(n) loop into an O(n**2) loop.  How is it that people just ignore this?

Comment: It's the difference between the code running with a large buffer vs. taking so long it doesn't terminate.  Try running it with a data length of 1MB and see how it does without that bug fix.  The bug turns 1,000,000 into 1,000,000,000,000.

Comment: It is a detail to optimize but it should never have been written that way to start. The code is actually more complex and less clear with `strlen(data)` being used three times instead of using a variable and calling `strlen(data)` once so only a well chosen variable name is seen in the code three times.